# Side-by-side versions of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I have VS 2015 Community full pack installed (44 as far as I saw) and I have to do a project in VS 2010 C# Express (I have to make a video about using that interface for my classmates at high-school, so I can explain them how to implement a database).

The idea is that I want to know if I can install VS 2010 and still keep the VS 2015 and then after I finish, uninstall 2010 safely (I have spent 4 hours installing VS 2015 and I don't want to waste that time again).

I've searched before posting this but one source of information I saw indicated that I can't do it, and somewhere else I saw that I can do it -- so I don't know what to believe. (sorry for my poor english)

Comment: Yes, you can install them both.

Comment: The following makes vague recommendations about trying to ensure the order of installation follows the release order of the versions -- meaning that MS is recommending that VS2010 be installed prior to VS2015: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx  However, they do not specify any specific problems you might encounter if you do not follow this recommendation.  The same post indicates that uninstalling one version will remove VS file associations for ALL version -- along with instructions on how to correct this problem.

Comment: As a side note, VS 2010 is a pain to uninstall. [Microsoft published a tool to uninstall it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2010/08/23/visual-studio-2010-uninstall-utility/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been installing a half dozen versions of visual studio side by side for years. I've never had a problem, with any version of VS or express. I install them in any order I choose. I've even uninstalled them, although I do that far less frequently and can't vouch for its absolute reliability. Naturally it isn't tested as well as the side by side installation. I would recommend leaving vs2010 til youve run out of disk space, at least.

[image: Several VS installed simultaneously]